# Implementing Harris Corner detector, by following standard material, it ends up detecting edges

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, corner-detection

Hi Thanks for your attention, I'm trying to implement Harris Corner Detection Algorithm, and have been following the standard Algorithm given on most souces one of them being [Wiki Page](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/harris-corner-detection) I follow all the procedure as per the algorithm, and I use sobel filters for computing gradient gx and gy, but the result ends up being a edge detector ( which ended up surprisingly better than the canny edge detector I implemented :O ) I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Core.h

```
#ifndef CORE
#define CORE

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#endif
```

Utils.h

```
#ifndef UTILS
#define UTILS

#include "Core.h"

static void displayImage(Mat &img, unsigned int time = 0,
                         string title = "frame") {
  imshow(title, img);
  waitKey(time);
}

static bool isValidPoint(Mat &img, int x, int y) {
  int rows = img.rows;
  int cols = img.cols;
  return (x >= 0 and x < rows and y >= 0 and y < cols);
}

static void performDiff(Mat img1, Mat img2) {
  int rows = img1.rows;
  int cols = img2.cols;
  Mat diff(rows, cols, CV_8U);
  bool zero = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      int d = (static_cast<int>(img1.at<u_char>(i, j)) -
               static_cast<int>(img2.at<u_char>(i, j)));
      diff.at<u_char>(i, j) = d;
      if (d != 0)
        zero = false;
    }
  }
  displayImage(diff, 0, "diff image");
}

static int getValIntOf(Mat &img, int x, int y) {
  return static_cast<int>(img.at<u_char>(x, y));
}

#endif
```

GaussianTransform.h

```
#ifndef GUASSIAN_TRANSFORM
#define GUASSIAN_TRANSFORM


static vector<vector<double>> getGuassianKernal(int size, double sigma) {
  vector<vector<double>> Kernal(size, vector<double>(size, 0.0));
  double sum = 0.0;
  int center = size / 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      int x = i - center;
      int y = j - center;
      Kernal[i][j] = exp(-(x * x + y * y) / (2 * sigma * sigma));
      sum += Kernal[i][j];
    }
  }
  if (sum != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        Kernal[i][j] /= sum;
      }
    }
  }
  return Kernal;
}


static Mat guassianFilterTransform(Mat &img, int FiltSize = 3,
                                   double Sigma = 1.5) {
  vector<vector<double>> filter = getGuassianKernal(FiltSize, Sigma);
  int trows = img.rows - FiltSize + 1;
  int tcols = img.cols - FiltSize + 1;
  Mat transformed(trows, tcols, CV_8U);
  for (int i = 1; i <= trows - 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= tcols - 2; j++) {
      double tval = 0;
      for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
          tval = tval + (filter[x + 1][y + 1] *
                         static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
        }
      }
      transformed.at<u_char>(i, j) = static_cast<u_char>(tval);
    }
  }
  return (transformed);
}

#endif
```

Harris.cpp

```
#ifndef HARRIS_CORNER
#define HARRIS_CORNER

#include "../../BasicTransforms/GaussianTransform.h"
#include "../../Utils/Core/Core.h"
#include "../../Utils/Core/Utils.h"

double computeCornerResponseFunc(vector<vector<double>> &StructMat) {
  double det =
      StructMat[0][0] * StructMat[1][1] - StructMat[0][1] * StructMat[1][0];
  double trace = StructMat[0][0] + StructMat[1][1];
  return (det + (0.04) * (trace * trace));
}

Mat detectHarrisCorners(Mat &img) {
  int filtSize = 3;
  vector<vector<int>> filtery, filterx;
  filtery = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
  filterx = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
  int trows = img.rows - filtSize + 1;
  int tcols = img.cols - filtSize + 1;
  Mat gradMag(trows, tcols, CV_8U);
  Mat gradDir(trows, tcols, CV_64F);
  Mat result(trows, tcols, CV_8U);
  double Thrs = 200;
  vector<vector<double>> gaussianKernal = getGuassianKernal(3, 1.5);
  for (int i = 1; i <= trows - 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= tcols - 2; j++) {
      double gradX = 0;
      double gradY = 0;
      for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
          gradX =
              gradX + gaussianKernal[x + 1][y + 1] *
                          (filterx[x + 1][y + 1] *
                           static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
          gradY =
              gradY + gaussianKernal[x + 1][y + 1] *
                          (filtery[x + 1][y + 1] *
                           static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
        }
      }
      vector<vector<double>> strtMtrx(2, vector<double>(2, 0.0));
      strtMtrx[0][0] = gradX * gradX;
      strtMtrx[1][1] = gradY * gradY;
      strtMtrx[0][1] = strtMtrx[1][0] = gradX * gradY;
      double CornerResponseFunc = computeCornerResponseFunc(strtMtrx);
      if (CornerResponseFunc >= Thrs) {
        result.at<u_char>(i, j) = 255;
      }
      double tval = sqrt(gradX * gradX + gradY * gradY);
      if (gradX == 0.00) {
        gradDir.at<double>(i, j) = (gradY >= 0 ? M_PI / 2.0 : -M_PI / 2.0);
      } else {
        gradDir.at<double>(i, j) = atan(gradY / gradX);
      }
      gradDir.at<double>(i, j) *= (180.0 / M_PI);
      gradDir.at<double>(i, j) = abs(gradDir.at<double>(i, j));
      gradMag.at<u_char>(i, j) = static_cast<u_char>(tval);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < trows - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < tcols - 1; j++) {
      double angle = gradDir.at<double>(i, j);
      double neigh1, neigh2;
      if ((angle >= 0 and angle < 22.5) or (angle >= 157.5 && angle < 180)) {
        neigh1 = gradMag.at<u_char>(i, j + 1);
        neigh2 = gradMag.at<u_char>(i, j - 1);
      } else if ((angle >= 22.5 and angle < 67.5)) {
        neigh1 = gradMag.at<u_char>(i - 1, j + 1);
        neigh2 = gradMag.at<u_char>(i + 1, j - 1);
      } else if ((angle >= 67.5 and angle < 112.5)) {
        neigh1 = gradMag.at<u_char>(i - 1, j);
        neigh2 = gradMag.at<u_char>(i + 1, j);
      } else if ((angle >= 112.5 and angle < 157.5)) {
        neigh1 = gradMag.at<u_char>(i - 1, j - 1);
        neigh2 = gradMag.at<u_char>(i + 1, j + 1);
      } else {
        neigh1 = neigh2 = 0;
      }
      if (gradMag.at<u_char>(i, j) >= max(neigh1, neigh2))
        result.at<u_char>(i, j) = result.at<u_char>(i, j);
      else
        result.at<u_char>(i, j) = 0;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  string imPath =
      "/home/panirpal/workspace/Projects/ComputerVision/data/chess2.jpg";
  Mat img = imread(imPath, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  if (!img.empty()) {
    Mat gaussian = guassianFilterTransform(img);
    Mat out = detectHarrisCorners(gaussian);
    displayImage(out);
  } else
    cerr << "image not found! exiting...";
}
#endif
```

Result :
[image: Output]

Expected Output :
[image: Expected Output]

Tried to play around with the magic numbers like threshold value and k value of 0.04 in `computeCornerResponseFunc` To No use ends up detecting edges.

Edit : Made the suggested Changes, It is able to detect some corners now, But I feel Not quite there yet. Updated code. Although Non max impression isn't performed, but I feel it more of a post processing step on the base algorithm, here I think computing `Mat GradXYSqSmooth = guassianFilterTransform(GradXY, 1.3);` is Introducing some noise, I wonder if there is something I'm doing wrong here, Or should that noise be filtered out! By using something like median filter?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void displayImage(Mat &img, unsigned int time = 0, string title = "frame") {
  imshow(title, img);
  waitKey(time);
}

static double getDoubleValOf(Mat &img, int x, int y) {
  return static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(x, y));
}

static double square(double x) { return x * x; }

static double computeGaussianFunc(double x, double y, double mu, double sigma) {
  double val =
      exp(-0.5 * ((square((x - mu) / sigma)) + square((y - mu) / sigma))) /
      (2 * M_PI * sigma * sigma);
  return val;
}

static vector<vector<double>> getGuassianKernal(double sigma) {
  int size = 2 * ceil(3 * sigma) + 1;
  vector<vector<double>> Kernal(size, vector<double>(size, 0.0));
  double sum = 0.0;
  int center = size / 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      Kernal[i][j] = computeGaussianFunc(i, j, center, sigma);
      sum += Kernal[i][j];
    }
  }
  if (sum != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        Kernal[i][j] /= sum;
      }
    }
  }
  return Kernal;
}

static Mat guassianFilterTransform(Mat &img, double Sigma) {
  vector<vector<double>> filter = getGuassianKernal(Sigma);
  int FiltSize = filter.size();
  int trows = img.rows - FiltSize + 1;
  int tcols = img.cols - FiltSize + 1;
  // Final output
  Mat transformed(trows, tcols, CV_8U);
  for (int i = 0; i < trows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <tcols; j++) {
      double tval = 0;
      for (int x = 0; x <FiltSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <FiltSize; y++) {
          tval = tval + (filter[x][y] *
                         static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
          tval = min(tval,255.0);
          tval = max(tval,0.0);
        }
      }
      transformed.at<u_char>(i,j) = static_cast<u_char>(round(tval));
    }
  }
  return (transformed);
}

double computeCornerResponseFunc(vector<vector<double>> &StructMat) {
  double det =
      StructMat[0][0] * StructMat[1][1] - StructMat[0][1] * StructMat[1][0];
  double trace = StructMat[0][0] + StructMat[1][1];
  return (det - (0.04) * (trace * trace));
}


Mat computeStructureTensorMatrixAndCornerResponse(Mat &GradXSqSmooth,
                                                  Mat &GradYSqSmooth,
                                                  Mat &GradXYSqSmooth) {
  int rows = GradXSqSmooth.rows;
  int cols = GradXSqSmooth.cols;
  Mat ResponseMat(rows, cols, CV_8U);
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      vector<vector<double>> STM = {{getDoubleValOf(GradXSqSmooth, i, j),
                                     getDoubleValOf(GradXYSqSmooth, i, j)},
                                    {getDoubleValOf(GradXYSqSmooth, i, j),
                                     getDoubleValOf(GradYSqSmooth, i, j)}};
      double CornerRes = computeCornerResponseFunc(STM);
      if (CornerRes >= 200)
        ResponseMat.at<u_char>(i, j) = 255;
      else
        ResponseMat.at<u_char>(i, j) = 0;
    }
  }
  return ResponseMat;
}

// Try to Optimize for GradX this is not required we can directly compute
// GradXSq.
Mat detectHarrisCornersUpd(Mat &img) {
  int filtSize = 3;
  vector<vector<int>> filtery, filterx;
  filtery = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
  filterx = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
  int trows = img.rows - filtSize + 1;
  int tcols = img.cols - filtSize + 1;
  Mat GradX(trows, tcols, CV_64F);
  Mat GradY(trows, tcols, CV_64F);
  Mat gradDir(trows, tcols, CV_64F);
  Mat result(trows, tcols, CV_8U);
  double Thrs = 200;
  /*
    1) Derivative Calculation:

    Calculate the horizontal (Ix) and vertical (Iy) derivatives of the grayscale
    image using the Sobel operator: Ix = Sobel(I_gray, dx) Iy = Sobel(I_gray,
    dy) dx and dy are the Sobel operators in the x and y directions,
    respectively.
  */
  for (int i = 1; i <= trows - 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= tcols - 2; j++) {
      double gradX = 0;
      double gradY = 0;
      // Compute Sobel Gradients.
      for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
          gradX = gradX + (filterx[x + 1][y + 1] *
                           static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
          gradY = gradY + (filtery[x + 1][y + 1] *
                           static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
        }
      }
      GradX.at<double>(i, j) = gradX;
      GradY.at<double>(i, j) = gradY;
      // GradDir required for non maximum supression
      double tval = sqrt(gradX * gradX + gradY * gradY);
      if (gradX == 0.00) {
        gradDir.at<double>(i, j) = (gradY >= 0 ? M_PI / 2.0 : -M_PI / 2.0);
      } else {
        gradDir.at<double>(i, j) = atan(gradY / gradX);
      }
      gradDir.at<double>(i, j) *= (180.0 / M_PI);
      gradDir.at<double>(i, j) = abs(gradDir.at<double>(i, j));
    }
  }
  /*
    3. Derivative Products:
    Element wise product
    Ix2 = Ix * Ix
    Iy2 = Iy * Iy
    Ixy = Ix * Iy
  */
  Mat GradXSq(trows, tcols, CV_64F);
  Mat GradYSq(trows, tcols, CV_64F);
  Mat GradXY(trows, tcols, CV_64F);
  for (int i = 0; i < trows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tcols; j++) {
      GradXSq.at<double>(i, j) =
          GradX.at<double>(i, j) * GradX.at<double>(i, j);
      GradYSq.at<double>(i, j) =
          GradY.at<double>(i, j) * GradY.at<double>(i, j);
      GradXY.at<double>(i, j) = GradX.at<double>(i, j) * GradY.at<double>(i, j);

      GradXSq.at<u_char>(i, j) =
          static_cast<u_char>(min(GradXSq.at<double>(i, j), 255.0));
      GradYSq.at<u_char>(i, j) =
          static_cast<u_char>(min(GradYSq.at<double>(i, j), 255.0));
      GradXY.at<u_char>(i, j) =
          static_cast<u_char>(min(GradXY.at<double>(i, j), 255.0));
    }
  }
  /*
    Gaussian Smoothing:

    Apply Gaussian smoothing to each of the derivative products to reduce noise
    sensitivity: Ix2_smooth = GaussianBlur(Ix2, kernel_size) Iy2_smooth =
    GaussianBlur(Iy2, kernel_size) Ixy_smooth = GaussianBlur(Ixy, kernel_size)
  */
  Mat GradXSqSmooth = guassianFilterTransform(GradXSq, 1.3);
  displayImage(GradXSqSmooth);
  Mat GradYSqSmooth = guassianFilterTransform(GradYSq, 1.3);
  displayImage(GradYSqSmooth);
  Mat GradXYSqSmooth = guassianFilterTransform(GradXY, 1.3);
  displayImage(GradXYSqSmooth);
  Mat StructTensorMat = computeStructureTensorMatrixAndCornerResponse(
      GradXSqSmooth, GradYSqSmooth, GradXYSqSmooth);
  return StructTensorMat;
}


int main() {
  string imPath =
      "/home/panirpal/workspace/Projects/ComputerVision/data/images/chess2.jpg";
  Mat img = imread(imPath, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  if (!img.empty()) {
    displayImage(img);
    Mat gaussian = guassianFilterTransform(img,1.3);
    Mat out = detectHarrisCornersUpd(gaussian);
    displayImage(out);
  } else
    cerr << "image not found! exiting...";
  return 0;
}
```

GradXSqSmooth :
[image: XGradSqSmooth Img]

GradYSqSmooth :
[image: yGradSqSmooth]

GradXYSmooth :
[image: GradXYSmooth]

Output Updated :
[image: Output]

Comment: A fairly common typo among Indian users: it is "kern**e**l", not "kern**a**l".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. The most important one is that you are not applying the smoothing to the squared gradient images.

```cpp
          gradX =
              gradX + gaussianKernal[x + 1][y + 1] *
                          (filterx[x + 1][y + 1] *
                           static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
```

Here you are computing the convolution of the image with a kernel formed by element-wise multiplication of the Sobel kernel and the Gaussian kernel.  This just means you're not using the Sobel kernel, but something else entirely that I can't immediately analyze.

Element-wise multiplication and convolution are two different things, and they don't commute. The structure tensor *M* (as described in the link you provide) has, as the first element, *G**(*I*<sub>x</sub>*I*<sub>x</sub>). *I*<sub>x</sub> is the result of the Sobel filter. *I*<sub>x</sub>*I*<sub>x</sub> is the square of that (element-wise multiplication of the result, as you did). But the *G** part is a convolution with the Gaussian. This smoothing has to be applied after the element-wise multiplication. This is not the same as (*G***I*<sub>x</sub>*)(*G**I*<sub>x</sub>)!

---

Here's another issue:

```cpp
static_cast<u_char>(tval)
```

This casts a double `tval` to 8-bit unsigned integer. `tval` is guaranteed to be non-negative, but it could very well be larger than 255. If so, the cast will wrap, the value 256 will be written as 0. You have to clamp the value first:

```cpp
static_cast<u_char>(std::min(tval,255.0))
```

This one in `performDiff` is worse:

```cpp
      int d = (static_cast<int>(img1.at<u_char>(i, j)) -
               static_cast<int>(img2.at<u_char>(i, j)));
      diff.at<u_char>(i, j) = d
```

The result of the subtraction cannot be represented in an 8-bit unsigned integer. Where `img2` is larger, `diff` will have some positive value, for example -1 will be represented as 255. You need to take the absolute difference, and do the same clamping as I showed above.

---

The call `getGuassianKernal(3, 1.5)` does not return a Gaussian. Cutting off a Gaussian with sigma 1.5 to 3 pixels leaves something much more similar to a filter with uniform weights than a Gaussian. I explain this in more detail [here](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695/). For a sigma of 1.5 we'd typically use a kernel of size `2*ceil(3*1.5)+1`, which is 11. At the very minimum you need `2*ceil(2*1.5)+1 = 7` (less precise but faster).

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, I will have to work your answer carefully into my code, many Thanks for the answer Cris, I went through your blog, This might feel cringy but wow that was simply great, I like your way of explaining simple, crisp and to the point!! I dropped you a follow request on Linkedin, I work in llvm compilers, and this is something I picked up for fun.

Comment: And oh yes I always felt that casting double to an unsigned int is horrible, ( it feels sickening tbh ) and maybe this is what I needed because I've been trying to find c++ implementations to no use, but couldn't find any, so it was sort of a compromise I was hoping to correct at some point. I appreciate that you did, and about ```performDiff``` again something quick and dirty, but I'm happy to be corrected. Thanks a ton! Cheers

Comment: @PawanNirpal Glad you found this and my blog useful. I also have a post that discusses the Structure Tensor, if you want to learn more about it: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/1132/

Comment: Hi  @CrisLuengo I got busy doing the refactoring and ran into this other fundamental issue with guassian blur, could you help me with this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873833/computing-gussian-blur-transform-issues-with-kernal-computation-and-normalizatio

Comment: Did the fixes as you suggested, ( after fixing Gaussian filter to a great extent ) Only consider the updated code, I still feel there is something that is not up to the mark, particularly in computing ```Mat GradXYSqSmooth```

Comment: @PawanNirpal `GradXY.at<u_char>()` doesn't make sense, `GradXY` has `double` pixels, not `u_char`. You must match the type to that used when creating the image. Also, `GradXY` can be negative, and you should not clip any of these values to 255. You need to keep them as doubles, and do the `computeStructureTensorMatrixAndCornerResponse()` computations with doubles. Don't threshold the Harris response, write the actual response values to an image, then look for local maxima in the result. It's about finding peaks, not about finding pixels above a certain value.

Comment: You mean Keep The Gx*Gx, Gy*Gy and Gx*Gy computation in doubles, but then what about Gaussian smoothening, it will require a u_char image right ?and not a CV_64F matrix?  The rest I understood.

Comment: @PawanNirpal Yes, you’ll have to apply the Gaussian smoothing to the floating-point data, meaning that function must be updated to use `double` instead of `u_char`. — You could also use `float` everywhere instead of `double`, to save on memory. Single precision float is more than enough for your goals. — Also, OpenCV’s built-in Gaussian smoothing function will work on single and double floating-point images, you really don’t need to implement that yourself.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo I was able to get Harris to work and it worked splendidly by following your suggestions. Could you help me with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936719/sift-feature-transform-not-detecting-correct-incomplete-scale-space-extremas