# Issues in Gaussian blur transform with kernel computation and normalization

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, gaussianblur

I am currently trying to implement Gaussian blurring *myself* for learning purposes. The blurring effect does not take place. Instead the image contrast is enhanced.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void displayImage(Mat &img, unsigned int time = 0, string title = "frame") {
  imshow(title, img);
  waitKey(time);
}

bool isValidPoint(Mat &img, int x, int y) {
  int rows = img.rows;
  int cols = img.cols;
  return (x >= 0 and x < rows and y >= 0 and y < cols);
}

static double square(double x) { return x * x; }

static double computeGaussianFunc(double x, double y, double mu, double sigma) {
  double val =
      exp(-0.5 * ((square((x - mu) / sigma)) + square((y - mu) / sigma))) /
      (2 * M_PI * sigma * sigma);
  return val;
}

double norm2(double val,double minVal,double maxVal){
  double range = (maxVal-minVal);
  double newVal  = (val-minVal)/range;
  return (int(255*newVal));
}

//  oldMin,  oldMax,  newMin,  newMax,  oldVal
double getNormalizedValue(double oldMin, double oldMax, double newMin,
                          double newMax, double oldVal) {
  double oldRange = (oldMax - oldMin);
  double newRange = (newMax - newMin);
  double newVal = (newMin + ((newRange * (oldVal - oldMin)) / (oldRange)));
  return newVal;
}

static vector<vector<double>> getGuassianKernal(double sigma) {
  int size = 2 * ceil(3 * sigma) + 1;
  vector<vector<double>> Kernal(size, vector<double>(size, 0.0));
  double sum = 0.0;
  int center = size / 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      int x = i - center;
      int y = j - center;
      Kernal[i][j] = computeGaussianFunc(i, j, size / 2, sigma);
      sum += Kernal[i][j];
    }
  }
  if (sum != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        Kernal[i][j] /= sum;
      }
    }
  }
  return Kernal;
}

static Mat guassianFilterTransformExp(Mat &img, double Sigma) {
  vector<vector<double>> filter = getGuassianKernal(Sigma);
  int FiltSize = filter.size();
  int trows = img.rows - FiltSize + 1;
  int tcols = img.cols - FiltSize + 1;
  // Final output
  Mat transformed(trows, tcols, CV_8U);
  // intermidiate matrix using for normalizing.
  Mat inter(trows, tcols, CV_64F);
  // min and max values of value after convolving with filter for normalization
  double minVal = 10000.0;
  double maxVal = 0.0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= trows - 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= tcols - 2; j++) {
      double tval = 0;
      for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
          tval = tval + (filter[x + 1][y + 1] *
                         static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
          minVal = min(minVal,tval);
          maxVal = max(maxVal,tval);
        }
      }
      inter.at<double>(i,j) = tval;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < trows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <tcols; j++) {
      double val = inter.at<double>(i,j);
      double newVal = norm2(val,minVal,maxVal);
      cout<<"Computed Val : "<<val<<" Src : "<<static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i, j))<<"  Normalized : "<<newVal<<'\n';
      transformed.at<u_char>(i,j) = static_cast<u_char>(min(255.0,newVal));
    }
  }
  return (transformed);
}


int main() {
  string imPath =
      "/home/panirpal/workspace/Projects/ComputerVision/data/images/chess2.jpg";
  Mat img = imread(imPath, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  if (!img.empty()) {
    displayImage(img);
    Mat out = guassianFilterTransformExp(img,1.3);
    displayImage(out);
  } else
    cerr << "image not found! exiting...";
  return 0;
}
```

On debugging I get multiple observations. First of all, I am computing kernel size based on sigma `2 * ceil(3 * sigma) + 1;` found on the Internet. So kernel size comes to be 9 ( sigma given = 1.3 , 2*(ceil(3*1.3) + 1 ). And kernel values come to be pretty small, when the filter is convolved/cross co-relation operation with the image patch, the resulting value ( denoted as `tval` in code) comes to be fairly small, and I suppose no surprises there. Then I try to normalize this `tval` to a range 0-255, since rendering `tval` as is would be resulting in a near blacked out image, I used one of the normalization techniques mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376600/normalizing-a-list-of-doubles-to-range-1-to-1-or-0-255) and following is some logs I collected to get a sense of what is going on, Computed val stands for `tval` Src stands for the orignal ( grayscale pixel value in source image ) and Normalized stands for `newVal` in code. The strange part is the Normalized values are higher than source they should be lower and smoothened. And the output also reflects the same.
What could I be doing wrong here?

```
Computed Val : 2.25082 Src : 167  Normalized : 177
Computed Val : 2.21529 Src : 161  Normalized : 174
Computed Val : 2.27372 Src : 159  Normalized : 179
Computed Val : 2.36755 Src : 160  Normalized : 186
Computed Val : 2.39062 Src : 177  Normalized : 188
Computed Val : 2.32093 Src : 174  Normalized : 182
Computed Val : 1.25675 Src : 168  Normalized : 99
Computed Val : 0.495057 Src : 91  Normalized : 39
Computed Val : 1.14986 Src : 39  Normalized : 90
Computed Val : 2.07179 Src : 64  Normalized : 163
Computed Val : 2.34365 Src : 132  Normalized : 184
Computed Val : 2.39052 Src : 172  Normalized : 188
```

Input image (named chess2.jpg):

[image: input]

Output:

[image: output]

Note: ensure OpenCV is built on your machine. Can be found in the [OpenCV install guide](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html).

The command used to build the code:

```bash
g++ exp.cpp -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.8.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.8.0 -lm -o exp
```

Expected output to be blurred image.

Comment: I see typo here: `Kernal[i][j] = computeGaussianFunc(i, j, size / 2, sigma);` I think plan was to use `x, y` here not `i, j`.

Comment: When you use OpenCV you should use it all the way. There is build in Gaussian blur and you should use this. This will give you a great performance boost and reduce risks of such mistakes (less code to test).

Comment: @MarekR This question was edited, and apparently the editor left out important details that I am in a learning phase, No matter how much we go through the theory, there is no substitute for real work, and besides this isn't for production code, and as for perf and fine-tuning, I will be using OpenMP and compiler auto-vectorization in further revisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Gaussian filter function, you create a Gaussian kernel of the right sizes, you read those sizes and adjust the loop over the image according to it, but then the inner loops are:

```cpp
      for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
```

which only iterate over the top-left 3x3 region of the kernel.

I don't like it when a filter function returns a smaller image than it got as input, because it makes it hard to combine the filter result with the original. But given that you do return a smaller image, you could simplify your code by not worrying about where the center of the kernel is:

```cpp
static Mat guassianFilterTransformExp(Mat &img, double Sigma) {
  vector<vector<double>> filter = getGuassianKernal(Sigma);
  int FiltSize = filter.size();
  int trows = img.rows - FiltSize + 1;
  int tcols = img.cols - FiltSize + 1;
  Mat transformed(trows, tcols, CV_8U);
  for (int i = 0; i < trows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tcols; j++) {
      double tval = 0;
      for (int x = 0; x < FiltSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < FiltSize; y++) {
          tval = tval + (filter[x][y] *
                         static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
        }
      }
      tval = std::min(tval, 255.0);
      tval = std::max(tval, 0.0);
      transformed.at<u_char>(i,j) = static_cast<u_char>(std::round(tval));
    }
  }
  return (transformed);
}
```

This simply removes all the `+1` and `-1` operations, which were meant for the 3x3 kernel and would have been replaced by `+FiltSize/2` and `-FiltSize/2`. (I've also removed the normalization part, which you shouldn't need.)

Note that the Gaussian is separable, which means you can implement this filter much more efficiently. Also `vector<vector<double>>` is a highly inefficient way to store a 2D matrix, and `img.at<u_char>()` is the least efficient way to access a pixel when in a loop over all image pixels. But I assume this is a learning exercise and not meant for serious production work. If this is meant for production, please use a library that already implements the operation efficiently.

---

There are other issues with the code, I didn't comb though all of it. For example, [as Marek R mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873833/issues-in-gaussian-blur-transform-with-kernel-computation-and-normalization/77874833#comment137288093_77873833),

```cpp
Kernal[i][j] = computeGaussianFunc(i, j, size / 2, sigma);
```

should be

```cpp
Kernal[i][j] = computeGaussianFunc(x, y, size / 2, sigma);
                                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: As a follow-up, what is a better way to store a 2d matrix, also how to efficiently access a pixel value in a loop?

Comment: @PawanNirpal See for example here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/202972/151754 — To access OpenCV pixel data, use either an image iterator, or get a pointer to the data and compute the index manually.

Comment: Thanks, Cris, I will check  that out, also I've updated the Harris corner detection and I see some improvement there in corners getting detected there but not quite, can you check my edit here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847011/implementing-harris-corner-detector-by-following-standard-material-it-ends-up

Answer (score 0):

After all the corrections and submitting the fixed issues, ( Will address padding and performance issues in a subsequent refactoring ) Thanks To @CrisLuengo and @MarekR for pointing out the issues.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void displayImage(Mat &img, unsigned int time = 0, string title = "frame") {
  imshow(title, img);
  waitKey(time);
}

bool isValidPoint(Mat &img, int x, int y) {
  int rows = img.rows;
  int cols = img.cols;
  return (x >= 0 and x < rows and y >= 0 and y < cols);
}

static double square(double x) { return x * x; }

static double computeGaussianFunc(double x, double y, double mu, double sigma) {
  double val =
      exp(-0.5 * ((square((x - mu) / sigma)) + square((y - mu) / sigma))) /
      (2 * M_PI * sigma * sigma);
  return val;
}

static vector<vector<double>> getGuassianKernal(double sigma) {
  int size = 2 * ceil(3 * sigma) + 1;
  vector<vector<double>> Kernal(size, vector<double>(size, 0.0));
  double sum = 0.0;
  int center = size / 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      // x and y removed here, not required because computeGaussianFunc already handles (i - center) (j - center)
      Kernal[i][j] = computeGaussianFunc(i, j, center, sigma);
      sum += Kernal[i][j];
    }
  }
  if (sum != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        Kernal[i][j] /= sum;
      }
    }
  }
  return Kernal;
}

static Mat guassianFilterTransformExp(Mat &img, double Sigma) {
  vector<vector<double>> filter = getGuassianKernal(Sigma);
  int FiltSize = filter.size();
  int trows = img.rows - FiltSize + 1;
  int tcols = img.cols - FiltSize + 1;
  // Final output
  Mat transformed(trows, tcols, CV_8U);
  for (int i = 0; i < trows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <tcols; j++) {
      double tval = 0;
      for (int x = 0; x <FiltSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <FiltSize; y++) {
          tval = tval + (filter[x][y] *
                         static_cast<double>(img.at<u_char>(i + x, j + y)));
          tval = min(tval,255.0);
          tval = max(tval,0.0);
        }
      }
      transformed.at<u_char>(i,j) = static_cast<u_char>(round(tval));
    }
  }
  return (transformed);
}


int main() {
  string imPath =
      "/home/panirpal/workspace/Projects/ComputerVision/data/images/chess2.jpg";
  Mat img = imread(imPath, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  if (!img.empty()) {
    displayImage(img);
    Mat out = guassianFilterTransformExp(img,1.5);
    displayImage(out);
  } else
    cerr << "image not found! exiting...";
  return 0;
}
```

Output is now blurred.
[image: Output]